# How to prove $x^T\Sigma x$ is quadratic?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, bayesian

How to prove $x^T\Sigma x$ is quadratic? where $\Sigma$ is covariant varible(symmetric matrix)

I did simple calculation with 3x2 matrix , 2x2 covariance, 2x3 matrix. the result is 3x3 matrix. But how to prove it's quadrtic?

$x^T\Sigma x = \Sigma x_i a_{ij} x_j$ so what?

Comment: what do you think the word quadratic means?

Comment: @WillJagy, $ax^2 + bx +c =0$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form   and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form_(statistics)

Comment: Calling gpt-training BS on this.

Comment: Yiff, take$ \Sigma =  \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
4 & 1 \\ 
1 &  - 3 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$    please multiply your $x^T \Sigma x$  where the entries of (column vector) $x$  are $x_1, x_2$ and tell me what you get

Comment: ‘@WillJagy: a nice challenge.

Comment: @WillJagy, $\left(\begin{matrix}
-4 & -2 & 0 \\
-2 & 12 & 26 \\
0 & 26 & 52
\end{matrix}\right)$. im using $123456$ $3\times2$ and $2\times3$, I cannot find anything interesting